# Why does Rust require a `'static` lifetime for this variable?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to understand why Rust makes a type have `'static` lifetime.

Please take a look at [this](https://github.com/smoltcp-rs/smoltcp/blob/master/examples/client.rs#L37) code:

```
let tcp_tx_buffer = TcpSocketBuffer::new(vec![0; 128]);
```

VSCode tells me that the type of `tcp_tx_buffer` is

```
smoltcp::storage::RingBuffer<'static, u8>
```

but if we find the `new` [method](https://github.com/smoltcp-rs/smoltcp/blob/master/src/storage/ring_buffer.rs#L35) on `RingBuffer`:

```
pub fn new<S>(storage: S) -> RingBuffer<'a, T>
    where S: Into<ManagedSlice<'a, T>>,
{
    RingBuffer {
        storage: storage.into(),
        read_at: 0,
        length:  0,
    }
}
```

there's no `'static` lifetime on the return. In fact the lifetime is the same as the input, `'a`. If `let tcp_tx_buffer` were outside `main`, I'd guess it's `static`, but it has its own scope. Or does Rust consider `main` to have a `'static` lifetime?

Comment: Because the lifetime is irrelevant, ManagedSlice is basically a Cow, the lifetime is there in case the value is a borrow (an actual slice). Since you're giving it an owned value there is no lifetime for which the object would be invalid, so it can get the "widest" possible lifetime, which is `'static`.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature on `new` says that it returns a `RingBuffer` which carries a specific lifetime; it is defined to be the same lifetime as the one carried by whatever the `storage`-parameter returns as part of `ManagedSlice` when `Into<ManagedSlice>` is called on it. That is, the `storage`-parameter gets to decide the lifetime carried by the `RingBuffer`-value.

You are passing an owned `Vec` into `TcpSocketBuffer::new()`. An owned `Vec` which does not contain reference-types is itself `'static`. `TcpSocketBuffer` can (due to its implementation) `Into<ManagedSlice>`, where `ManagedSlice` carries the lifetime original `Vec`'s lifetime `'static`. This is where `'static` comes from.

It may be helpful when thinking about `'static` that this lifetime does not mean that the value *has to* live forever. It just means that the value *can be made* to live forever. This is true for all values which do not contain references that themselves have a lifetime shorter than `'static`. For example, a  `String::new()`is `'static` because it can be made to live as long as we want (simply by not dropping it). A `Foo<'a> { bar: &'a str }` can only be made to live for as long as `'a`, because `Foo` contains a reference which *may* be shorter than `'static`.

From the moment of creation, your owned `Vec` can be made to live for as long as we want and this property is carried through to `RingBuffer`.